# How to display data in Label from data store in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, labelfield, extjs-mvc

I want to display data that i receive from a data store. One way that i have tried, is to take a text field make it disabled and then set its value with store data. 
But i don't think it is the correct solution so i am trying to use label instead and I am not getting how it can be done. Can you guys can point me to correct way of doing it.? Any help appreciated .

Thanks,
Mehul Makwana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently tried to solve this problem by creating a 'label' form component. I posted about it in a blog article I wrote on [Sencha/PhoneGap](http://www.codesta.com/blog/2011/5/23/sencha-touchphonegap-tips-and-tricks.html). Here is the code:

```
Ext.form.LabelField = function(config){
    Ext.form.LabelField.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
};

Ext.extend(Ext.form.LabelField, Ext.form.Field,  {
    isField: true,
    value: '',
    renderSelectors: {fieldEl: '.x-form-labelfield'},
    renderTpl: [
       '<tpl if="label">',
           '<div class="x-form-label"><span>{label}</span></div>',
       '</tpl>',
       '<div class="x-form-label x-form-labelfield" style="width:70%; text-align:right"><span>{value}</span></div>',
    ],
    setValue:function(val) {
        this.value = val;
        if(this.rendered){
             this.fieldEl.update('<span>' + val + '</span>');
        }
        return this;
    },

});

Ext.reg('labelfield', Ext.form.LabelField);
```

Let me know if this does the trick.

Comment: great. If you can help me bit more, how can i bind value with Store data. ?

Comment: It should act like a regular field, you will need to add the name property to it and create the FormPanel with the data from the object.  I ended up using it in a different manner, so you may need to experiment.

Answer (score 2):

This post is a little old but I was research the for same topic and ended up using a different approach.

I'm using Sencha Touch v2.0. I create the label and place it inside the form.Panel as one would normally do. I then configured the label tpl in designer to include the model fields. When applying the values to the formpanel, I also invoke the apply() method on the label tpl. The following working sample illustrate it.

app.js:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
  enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
  views: [
    'MyFormPanel'
  ],
  name: 'MyApp',

  launch: function() {

    Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyFormPanel', {fullscreen: true});
  } 

});
```

view.MyFormPanel.js

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyFormPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.myformpanel',

    config: {
    items: [
        {
        xtype: 'label',
        itemId: 'myLabel',
        tpl: [
            'Hello, {firstName} {lastName}, please change your email below:',
            ''
        ]
        },
        {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        label: 'Email:'
        }
    ],
    listeners: [
        {
        fn: 'onFormpanelInitialize',
        event: 'initialize'
        }
    ]
    },

    onFormpanelInitialize: function(component, options) {
    var person = Ext.decode("{firstName: 'John',lastName: 'Dow',email: 'jd@somewhere.com'}");
    // apply value to the form
    this.setValues(person);
    // get the updated text for the label
    var label = this.down('#myLabel');
    var html = label.getTpl().apply(person);
    label.setHtml(html);

    }

});
```

So the idea is save the label template in the label.tpl field, then get the runtime label value using apply() method of Template, then set the label text to it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you mistagrooves. That was exactly what I was looking for. I reccomand removing *x-form-label* class and using these styles:

```
.x-form-labelfield {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  box-flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: .4em;
  border: 0;
  min-height: 2.5em;
  display: block;
  background: white none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: is there any specific reason for changing the style. ?